# Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings

Tags: php, random

How can I generate a (pseudo)random alpha-numeric string, something like: 'd79jd8c' in PHP?

Comment: The Solution is short and unique.
Refer this Link http://stackoverflow.com/a/34467730/4345141

Comment: The method [`Random::alphanumericString($length)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Random) does what you want. If you want to build this yourself, don’t use any random source other than PHP’s built-in `random_bytes` or `random_int`.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

First make a string with all your possible characters:

```
 $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
```

You could also use [range()](http://php.net/range) to do this more quickly.

Then, in a loop, choose a random number and use it as the index to the `$characters` string to get a random character, and append it to your string:

```
 $string = '';
 $max = strlen($characters) - 1;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
      $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $max)];
 }
```

`$random_string_length` is the length of the random string.

Comment: This implementation is also nice if you wish to remove characters that look the same such as "l" and "1", "O" and "0". This is worthwhile when generating new passwords for users.

Comment: I also use this technique and remove all the vowels so I don't accidentally give someone something rude for a password.

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis after the "- 1" and before the "]"

Comment: Minor improvement: [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt_rand) is a drop-in replacement for `rand()`, and is better.

Comment: Executing `strlen()` each iteration isn't good. Assign `strlen($characters) - 1` to a variable and perform strlen out of the cycle. Not critical in this case, but it's just [Mauvais ton](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/Mauvais+Ton).

Comment: `range` definitely wouldn't do this more quickly. Nothing is quicker than a hard-coded string of 36 characters.

Comment: Consider using [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) if you need a cryptographically secure random.

Comment: what is the propability of getting a duplicate string with this code?

Answer (score 18):

I like this function for the job

```
function randomKey($length) {
    $pool = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a', 'z'),range('A', 'Z'));

    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $pool[mt_rand(0, count($pool) - 1)];
    }
    return $key;
}

echo randomKey(20);
```

Answer (score 14):

Generate cryptographically strong, random (potentially) 8-character string using the [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes) function:

```
echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4));
```

Procedural way:

```
function randomString(int $length): string
{
    return bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
}
```

**Update:**

PHP7 introduced the `random_x()` functions which should be even better. If you come from PHP 5.X, use excellent [paragonie/random_compat](https://packagist.org/packages/paragonie/random_compat) library which is a polyfill for [random_bytes()](http://php.net/random_bytes) and [random_int()](http://php.net/random_int) from PHP 7.

```
function randomString($length)
{
    return bin2hex(random_bytes($length));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

One line solution:

```
echo substr( str_shuffle( str_repeat( 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 10 ) ), 0, 7 );
```

You can change the substr parameter in order to set a different length for your string.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to pick a range of letters, where the: $range_start , $range_end is a value from the decimal column in the ASCII table.

I find that this method is nicer compared [to the method described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings#48125) where the range of characters is specifically defined within another string.

```
// range is numbers (48) through capital and lower case letters (122)
$range_start = 48;
$range_end   = 122;
$random_string = "";
$random_string_length = 10;

for ($i = 0; $i < $random_string_length; $i++) {
  $ascii_no = round( mt_rand( $range_start , $range_end ) ); // generates a number within the range
  // finds the character represented by $ascii_no and adds it to the random string
  // study **chr** function for a better understanding
  $random_string .= chr( $ascii_no );
}

echo $random_string;
```

See More:

- [chr](http://au.php.net/chr) function
- [mt_rand](http://au.php.net/mt_rand) function

Comment: This is nice although non-alphanumeric characters fall within that ACSII range.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old post but I'd like to contribute with a class I've created based on Jeremy Ruten's answer and improved with suggestions in comments:

```
    class RandomString
    {
      private static $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
      private static $string;
      private static $length = 8; //default random string length

      public static function generate($length = null)
      {

        if($length){
          self::$length = $length;
        }

        $characters_length = strlen(self::$characters) - 1;

        for ($i = 0; $i < self::$length; $i++) {
          self::$string .= self::$characters[mt_rand(0, $characters_length)];
        }

        return self::$string;

      }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple guys .... but remember each byte is random between 0 and 255 which for a random string will be fine.  Also remember you'll have two characters to represent each byte.

```
$str = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));  // 64 character string returned
```

Comment: By far the best answer and the shortest code! This should get more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code. It is similar to existing functions except that you can force special character count:

```php
function random_string() {
    // 8 characters: 7 lower-case alphabets and 1 digit
    $character_sets = [
        ["count" => 7, "characters" => "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"],
        ["count" => 1, "characters" => "0123456789"]
    ];
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_sets as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set["count"]; $i++) {
            $random = random_int(0, strlen($character_set["characters"]) - 1);
            $temp_array[] = $character_set["characters"][$random];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode("", $temp_array);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I missed something here, but [here's a way using the uniqid() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

Comment: `uniqid` is not random in any way. It's completely predictable. This question is very specifically looking for pseudorandom strings.

Answer (score 2):

I have made the following quick function just to play around with the `range()` function. It just might help someone sometime.

```
Function pseudostring($length = 50) {

    // Generate arrays with characters and numbers
    $lowerAlpha = range('a', 'z');
    $upperAlpha = range('A', 'Z');
    $numeric = range('0', '9');

    // Merge the arrays
    $workArray = array_merge($numeric, array_merge($lowerAlpha, $upperAlpha));
    $returnString = "";

    // Add random characters from the created array to a string
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $character = $workArray[rand(0, 61)];
        $returnString .= $character;
    }

    return $returnString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
echo generateRandomString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very easy way to do this, you can lean on existing PHP functions. This is the code I use:

`substr( sha1( time() ), 0, 15 )`

`time()` gives you the current time in seconds since epoch, `sha1()` encrypts it to a string of 0-9a-f, and `substr()` lets you choose a length. You don't have to start at character 0, and whatever the difference is between the two numbers will be the length of the string.

Answer (score 1):

First list the desired characters

```
$chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

Use the str_shuffle($string) function. This function will provide you a randomly shuffled string.

```
$alpha=substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 50);
```

50 is the Length of string.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy's answer is great. If, like me, you're unsure of how to implement range(), you can see my version using range().

```
<?php
$character_array = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
$string = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $string .= $character_array[rand(0, (count($character_array) - 1))];
    }
echo $string;
?>
```

This does the exact same thing as Jeremy's but uses merged arrays where he uses a string, and uses count() where he uses strlen().

Comment: it needs to be `range('a','z');`

Answer (score 0):

This is something I use:

```
$cryptoStrong = true; // can be false
$length = 16; // Any length you want
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $cryptoStrong);
$randomString = bin2hex($bytes);
```

You can see the [Docs for openssl_random_pseudo_bytes here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php), and the [Docs for bin2hex here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)

Answer (score 0):

1 line:

```
$FROM = 0; $TO = 'zzzz';
$code = base_convert(rand( $FROM ,base_convert( $TO , 36,10)),10,36);
echo $code;
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to do that with type hint / rand_int for real randomeness

```
function random_string(int $size): string
{
    $characters = array_merge(
        range(0, 9),
        range('A', 'Z')
    );

    $string = '';
    $max = count($characters) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $string .= $characters[random_int(0, $max)];
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function randomString($length = 8)
{
    $characters = implode([
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPORRQSTUWVXYZ',
        'abcdefghijklmnoprqstuwvxyz',
        '0123456789',
        //'!@#$%^&*?'
    ]);

    $charactersLength = strlen($characters) - 1;
    $string           = '';

    while ($length) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, $charactersLength)];
        --$length;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

Comment: You have different number of characters in lower and upper case strings. And does this code have any advantages over all other variants already published here?