# Bash: Add a random alphanumeric string at the end of files

Tags: bash, unix

I would like to come up with a bash script that would add a random alphanumeric string to the end of all the files.  I would like the string to have a length of 10.

So if I had the filename: hello.jpg
It would become: hello_v41e6ebadx_.jpg

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, I have quite a lot of ideas about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you generate passwords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101362/how-do-you-generate-passwords) covers alphanumeric string generation, the rest if just variable manipulation and file renaming

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in *.*
do
    name=${file%.*}
    ext=${file##*.}
    random=$(LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9' < /dev/urandom | head -c 10)
    mv "$file" "${name}_${random}_.${ext}"
done
```

You can also consider `mktemp`, if no "X"s in your file extensions are likely to trip it up.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: tr: illegal byte sequence

Comment: Try with LC_CTYPE=C in front of tr, to make it not attempt to parse anything as unicode.