# generating a random code in php?

Tags: php, random

i know this might seem silly, but i want to generate a random code of 8 characetrs, only numbers or letters using php. i needs this to generate a password for each user that signs up, thanks

Comment: Have you googled "php random password generator" - there's a whole lot of hits...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would rather use [md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) to generate passwords

**But you can use something like this if you want a custom:**

```
function createRandomPassword() { 

    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0; 
    $pass = '' ; 

    while ($i <= 7) { 
        $num = rand() % 33; 
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1); 
        $pass = $pass . $tmp; 
        $i++; 
    } 

    return $pass; 

}
```

Comment: using the `md5()` idea, you could take the `$pass` your are returning now and instead do `return substr(md5($pass), 0, 8);`

Comment: i presume the L and 1 are left on purpose! because they look alike?

Comment: The advantage of this over md5 or some other hash function is that you can leave out characters that look similar, such as the above example leaves out L and 1.

Comment: I'd now use something like this:

```
$chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789";

        $i = 0;
        $token = '';

        while ($i <= 7) {
            $num = \random_int(0, 33);
            $token .= $chars{$num};
            $i++;
        }
```
(uses CSPRNG/pure randomness PHP functions)

Answer (score 11):

What about something like this, for ease:

```
$pass = substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)) , 0, 8);
```

Answer (score 5):

A good or efficient method for doing this is:

```
public function generateRandomString($length = 8) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs092u3tuvwxyzaskdhfhf9882323ABCDEFGHIJKLMNksadf9044OPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

By changing $length variable you can generate alphanumeric code according to your need.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 

$uniqid = uniqid();

$rand_start = rand(1,5);

$rand_8_char = substr($uniqid,$rand_start,8);

?>
```

Comment: you might want to salt the time otherwise a hacker might be able to take advantage.  it's a long shot, but still possible.

Comment: I think 'long shot' is an understatement. ;)

Comment: still, all some hackers has, is time :-)

Comment: fine! did not do what you told me to do on principal, BUT I made the starting position for the substring random.  better? ;)

Comment: i just did a little research and it appears this whole back-and-forth was for naught, you can just add true to the second parameter of `uniqid()` and it will add entropy for unique values :-)

Comment: I thought that adds special characters? which he did not want in the password.

Answer (score 3):

This work like charm and you can choose the type of characters that will be generated like:
**"upper_case", "lower_case", "number", "special_character"**

```
function create_random_code($length = 8, $in_params = [])
{
    $in_params['upper_case']        = isset($in_params['upper_case']) ? $in_params['upper_case'] : true;
    $in_params['lower_case']        = isset($in_params['lower_case']) ? $in_params['lower_case'] : true;
    $in_params['number']            = isset($in_params['number']) ? $in_params['number'] : true;
    $in_params['special_character'] = isset($in_params['special_character']) ? $in_params['special_character'] : false;

    $chars = '';
    if ($in_params['lower_case']) {
        $chars .= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    }

    if ($in_params['upper_case']) {
        $chars .= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    }

    if ($in_params['number']) {
        $chars .= "0123456789";
    }

    if ($in_params['special_character']) {
        $chars .= "!@#$%^&*()_-=+;:,.";
    }

    return substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, $length);
}
```

To use it:

```
echo create_random_code(
    6,
    [
        'upper_case'        => true,
        'lower_case'        => true,
        'number'            => true,
        'special_character' => false
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `base64_encode()`, feed it some `rand()` numbers, and cut off the first 8 characters, which are definitely letters or numbers. That's not a totally random combination due to the input being just integers. But it's good enough for default user-passwords. (Else use `rand()` via `chr()` before encoding.)

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [`rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) function (and also a [`mt_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function that the docs claim is faster.)

So do something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$pwd = "";
while ( $i < 10) {
    if (mt_rand() % 2 == 0) {
        $pwd .= rand();
    } else {
        $pwd .= char(rand());
        // http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php
    }
    $i += 1;
}
```

Comment: another option would be to use `rand()` only once by setting the min & max number allowed ie- `$pwd = rand(10000000, 99999999);`

Comment: @Patrick -- good thought!  If speed is a problem then you can replace the interior random calls with string concatenation alone or a call to char.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, you can use the following to generate random codes:

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(10))
```

Note that here we use `random_bytes`, which was introduced in PHP 7 and uses a cryptographic random generator, something that is important if you want random codes to be hard to guess. `random_int` was also introduced in PHP 7 and likewise uses a cryptographic random generator.

Many other solutions for random value generation, including those involving `time()`, `microtime()`, `uniqid()`, `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, `str_shuffle()`, `array_rand()`, and `shuffle()`, are much more predictable and are unsuitable if the random string will serve as a password, a bearer credential, a nonce, a session identifier, a "verification code" or "confirmation code", or another secret value.

The code above generates a string of 20 hexadecimal characters (0 to 9, or A to F). If you want to use a bigger character set (such as all upper-case letters, all lower-case letters, and the 10 digits), this is a more involved process, but you have to use `random_int` rather than `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, `str_shuffle()`, etc., if the string will serve as a password, a "confirmation code", or another secret value. See an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings/1037136#1037136).

I also list [other things to keep in mind](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers) when generating unique identifiers, especially random ones.