# How can I generate a 6 digit unique number?

Tags: php, random

How can I generate a 6 digit unique number? I have verification mechanisms in place to check for duplicate entries.

Comment: why not use sequential numbers if thats the case? or use a timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php random x digit number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215979/php-random-x-digit-number)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
$six_digit_random_number = random_int(100000, 999999);
```

As all numbers between 100,000 and 999,999 are six digits, of course.

Comment: Do you know howmany random numbers generated from this method? what if get same random number?

Comment: @saleemahmed [That's the problem with randomness, you can never be sure](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).  No, really, it's quite possible for numbers to repeat and still be random.  This is fine.

Comment: The other solutions (Tim Cooper and Frosty Z) are better since they also produce numbers between 1 and 100,000.

Comment: @SamuelLindblom While this is true, those numbers are generated with zeros on the left, which may cause weirdness and side effects, including the possibility of being misinterpreted as octal numbers.  By keeping 100000 as the bottom number, you can be sure that it'll always be treated as the intended number.

Comment: These types of 6 digit codes are usually used for security purposes. As such it worth noting that in mt_rand docs it advises against using it for these purposes, "Caution This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead."

Comment: Indeedy, we didn't have `random_int` 10 years ago when I created this answer.  I've updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 51):

If you want it to start at `000001` and go to `999999`:

```
$num_str = sprintf("%06d", mt_rand(1, 999999));
```

Mind you, it's stored as a string.

Comment: Is that random (`mt_rand`) or sequential (start at * and go to *)?

Answer (score 16):

Another one:

```
str_pad(mt_rand(0, 999999), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Anyway, for uniqueness, you will have to check that your number hasn't been already used.

You tell that you **check for duplicates**, but be cautious since when most numbers will be used, the number of "attempts" (and therefore the time taken) for getting a new number will increase, possibly resulting in very long delays & wasting CPU resources.

I would advise, if possible, to keep track of available IDs in an array, then randomly choose an ID *among the available ones*, by doing something like this (if ID list is kept in memory):

```
$arrayOfAvailableIDs = array_map(function($nb) {
    return str_pad($nb, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}, range(0, 999999));

$nbAvailableIDs = count($arrayOfAvailableIDs);

// pick a random ID

$newID = array_splice($arrayOfAvailableIDs, mt_rand(0, $nbAvailableIDs-1), 1);
$nbAvailableIDs--;
```

You can do something similar even if the ID list is stored in a database.

Answer (score 11):

There are some great answers, but many use functions that are flagged as not cryptographically secure. If you want a random 6 digit number that is cryptographically secure you can use something like this:

```
$key = random_int(0, 999999);
$key = str_pad($key, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
return $key;
```

This will also include numbers like 000182 and others that would otherwise be excluded from the other examples.

You can also use a loop to make each digit random and generate random number with as many digits as you may need:

```
function generateKey($keyLength) {
    // Set a blank variable to store the key in
    $key = "";
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $keyLength; $x++) {
        // Set each digit
        $key .= random_int(0, 9);
    }
    return $key;
}
```

For reference, random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers that are suitable for use where unbiased results are critical, such as when shuffling a deck of cards for a poker game." - [php.net/random_int](https://www.php.net/random_int)

Comment: I was just looking for ideas / the most effective way to generate 6 digit two-factor authentication codes and this is hands down the best answer here.

Comment: P.S. I would edit but it says my queue is full. I would suggest the following edits: 1) "$key = str_pad(random_int(0, 999999), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);" (original answer specifies 9999999 which is seven digits), and 2) add the following reference: "random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers that are suitable for use where unbiased results are critical, such as when shuffling a deck of cards for a poker game." - https://www.php.net/random_int

Comment: Thanks man! your answer is concise and straight to the point

Comment: @caffeinatedbits good catch on the typo. I made your changes and added a second example.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another one:

```
substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,6);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
$file = 'count.txt';

//get the number from the file
$uniq = file_get_contents($file);

//add +1
$id = $uniq + 1 ;

// add that new value to text file again for next use
file_put_contents($file, $id);

// your unique id ready
echo $id;
?>
```

i hope this will work fine. i use the same technique in my website.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP 7.0+ I would suggest `random_int($min, $max)` *over* `mt_rand()`.

```
$randomSixDigitInt = \random_int(100000, 999999);
```

From php.net:

> Caution
>   This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

So this depends mostly on context.  I'll also add that as of PHP 7.1.0 `rand()` is now an alias to `mt_rand()`.

Cheers

Comment: why? you should tell a reason

Answer (score 5):

```
$characters = '123456789';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
$pin=$randomString;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will generate random 6 digit number

```html
<?php
    mt_rand(100000,999999);
?>
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and the one provided by @Charles, at Mar 28, 2011?

Comment: There is no difference.. :) @Trix

Answer (score 1):

I would use an algorithm, brute force could be as follows:

First time through loop:
Generate a random number between 100,000 through 999,999 and call that x1

Second time through the loop
Generate a random number between 100,000 and x1 call this xt2, then generate a random number between x1 and 999,999 call this xt3, then randomly choose x2 or x3, call this x2

Nth time through the loop
Generate random number between 100,000 and x1, x1 and x2, and x2 through 999,999 and so forth...

watch out for endpoints, also watch out for x1

Comment: but why all this complications just to generate random number?

Answer (score 1):

`<?php echo rand(100000,999999); ?>`

you can  generate random number

Comment: As this question is 6 years old, not sure how much this adds to the answers already posted.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest method to generate 6 digits random number

```
$data = random_int(100000, 999999);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$uniq = round(microtime(true));**

it generates 10 digit base on time
which is never be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Try this using uniqid and hexdec,

```
echo hexdec(uniqid());
```

Answer (score 0):

Among the answers given here before this one, [the one by "Yes Barry"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52284516/815724) is the most appropriate one.

```
random_int(100000, 999999)
```

Note that here we use `random_int`, which was introduced in PHP 7 and uses a cryptographic random generator, something that is important if you want random codes to be hard to guess. `random_bytes` was also introduced in PHP 7 and likewise uses a cryptographic random generator.

Many other solutions for random value generation, including those involving `time()`, `microtime()`, `uniqid()`, `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, `str_shuffle()`, `array_rand()`, and `shuffle()`, are much more predictable and are unsuitable if the random string will serve as a password, a bearer credential, a nonce, a session identifier, a "verification code" or "confirmation code", or another secret value.

The code above generates a string of 6 decimal digits. If you want to use a bigger character set (such as all upper-case letters, all lower-case letters, and the 10 digits), this is a more involved process, but you have to use `random_int` or `random_bytes` rather than `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, `str_shuffle()`, etc., if the string will serve as a password, a "confirmation code", or another secret value. See an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings/1037136#1037136), and see also: [generating a random code in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570980/generating-a-random-code-in-php/64472183#64472183)

I also list [other things to keep in mind](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers) when generating unique identifiers, especially random ones.