# How to generate an unique 8-digit integer number?

Tags: php, random

I want to generate a 8 digit random integer number using the PHP mt_rand() function.

I know the PHP mt_rand() function only takes 2 parameters: a minimum and a maximum value.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php random x digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215979/php-random-x-digit-number)

Answer (score 10):

**Try this**,

```
$num = str_pad(mt_rand(1,99999999),8,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

use str_pad with mt_rand

Comment: I believe this is actually the closest to what OP is actually asking for. A 8 digit number, it doesn't say it has to start with `10000000` as everyone else assumes. However why do you assume 1 is the minimum number ;-) why not `00000000`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want exactly 8 digit numbers then you have to specify min and max value in `mt_rand`. Try it like below:

```
echo mt_rand(10000000,99999999);
```

So that it will always return **8** digit number. (between `10000000` & `99999999`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. It will return the number between the range **10000000 - 99999999**

```
<?php
echo(mt_rand(10000000,99999999) . "<br>");
```