# PHP Class random number

Tags: php, codeigniter

**What i want to do:**

Generate single random number which will be passed to functions inside the class.

In other words while calling $this->random both one() and two() should return same value

**What is actually happening:**

I have multiple random numbers because rand() is getting called multiple times

**Important notes:**

I want to avoid storing the number inside the session or SQL

**How does my code look:**

```
    class Install
    {
        private $random= '';

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->random = rand(pow(10, 4-1), pow(10, 4)-1);

        }

         public function one()
         {
           echo $this->random; //example value = 3304
         }

         public function two()
         {
           echo $this-random; //example value = 2504
         }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for ruling out the two best options, session and SQL? Because you have to store them _somewhere_.

Comment: Because of sensitivity issue of the token i do not want to pass it to the user browser and because token is temporary and it can be many i do not want to store it in DB as well. Is not there a way to fix the variable after generation and pass it to the functions ?

Comment: So don't. Session variables are stored on the server.

Comment: Wait, do you just want the value to be static across all instances of the class? The code you've provided doesn't do what you claim, and your description is lacking in detail.

Comment: @Sammitch So basically what i need is to have same random value in both one() and two() functions. i will take a better look on how the session works as well.

Comment: But your code does work as is, but for the syntax error in your `two` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php random x digit number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215979/php-random-x-digit-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a consistent random number across both function calls to the *same instance* in the *same request*, then your code will work as-is.

If you just want a consistent random number across both function calls to the *same instance* in the *different requests*, then you need to use some form of persistent storage like the Session or a DB.

If you just want a consistent random number across both function calls to the *different instances* in the *same request*, then you need a class static variable.

```
class StaticRandom {
    private static $rand = NULL;

    public static function getRand() {
        if( is_null(self::$rand) ) {
            // this is also where you wouldput the session/DB bits if you
            // want to persist across requests.
            self::$rand = rand(pow(10, 4-1), pow(10, 4)-1);
        }
        return self::$rand;
    }

    public function instanceMethodOne() {
        return self::getRand();
    }

    public function instanceMethodTwo() {
        return self::getRand();
    }
}

$a = new StaticRandom();
$b = new StaticRandom();

var_dump(
    $a->instanceMethodOne(),
    $b->instanceMethodTwo()
);
```

Output:

```
int(4188)
int(4188)
```