# How to generate 16 digit number with certain prefix

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate 16 digit number with a specific prefix. For example, the first four-digit should be 1800

1800485480692246

This is what I achieved so far

```
<?php
function generatenumber($limit){
$code = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
$code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
}
return $code;
}
echo generatenumber(16);
?>
```

Comment: You are generate the whole 16 digit randomly, if you want a prefix 1800, you can generate 12 random digit and add 1800 at the begining: `1800 . generatenumber(12)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a four-digit prefix then you should generate a 12 (16-4) digit number and append the prefix to it:

```
function generatenumber($limit, $prefix){
    $code = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) { 
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
    }
    return $prefix.$code;
}

echo generatenumber(12, 1800); // 1800930423128799
```

Or just like @pistou mentioned, to keep the 16 as input:

```
function generatenumber($limit, $prefix){
    $code = '';
    if(strlen($prefix) > strlen($limit)) {
        for($i = 0; $i < ($limit - strlen($prefix)); $i++) { 
            $code .= mt_rand(0, 9); 
        }
    }
    return $prefix.$code;
}
```

This approach would also allow to have a prefix in any length, without chaning the code:

```
echo generatenumber(16, 1800); // 1800930423128799
echo generatenumber(16, 12345678); // 1234567841559624
```

See the ouput [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7b39b90ea366d69ced74ad1722ce2ed0e0a3fdc7)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216031/2099704), you could do as followed:

```
function generateNumber($limit=16, $prefix='') {
    $digits = $limit - strlen($prefix);
    $rand = str_pad(rand(0, pow(10, $digits)-1), $digits, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    return $prefix . $rand;
}

echo generateNumber(); // 0286940312944352
echo generateNumber(10); // 5532957240
echo generateNumber(16, 1800); // 1800045386499259
```