# Creating a Unique ID in MYSQL Using a Random Generator - Is it "safe" to Define an array to Exclude Known ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if it's safe to request all (unique id's) that's already within the database and store them into an array. Then disqualify them from the random generation process?

For example, IF I used this to store a unique id:

```
$six_digit_random_number = random_int(100000, 999999);
```

(Which I found on StackOverflow.) [Link to Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464906/how-can-i-generate-a-6-digit-unique-number)

Then imagine that I exclude each of the unique id's that already exist within the database:

1. Is this "safe" to do? (Security issues)
2. Would this cause any server issues? (Latency or other issues)

Here's some additional information:

- I wanted to design my own random generator (Done)
- I want to run a test before the "random generating function" starts to insure none of these values can be generated from the beginning. To do this, I chose to access my database and run a query that stores all known unique id's into an array.

The code that I have works fine. I, however, don't know whether or not it is safe to use it. Are there risk of it being hijacked somehow when I store it into an array? Will people be able to access to source and alter it if they turn off JavaScript and cookies? I just don't know enough about how the server side works so I just want to hear more about what is right/wrong about coding this way. I don't know how to ask the question better.

Comment: Using such a function in itself will not cause any security issues.  I would not rely on it in a securoty context, though.

Comment: Reading all IDs from a database and compare an ID will impact performance.. the more IDs, the more overhead.

Comment: Why not let the database generate the IDs? Or use a GUID instead of a numeric ID, to enhance the chances of uniqueness? Also, how should Javascript or cookies interfere in this process, if it runs completely on the server?

Comment: @NicoHaase People can turn off cookies and Javascript. This renders the coding useless. That's why instead of accessing a user's actual ID I wanted to generate an ID for each user separate from the user's true ID. Something that I can access to find the user's information and regenerate it after I access it.  I'm generating 8 random digits, 8 random letters (both capital and lowercase), and 8 random special chars. Then shuffle them and this creates the user's unique ID separate from the user's actual  unique ID. Note that I'm not talking about Primary & Unique keys.

Comment: Neither cookies nor Javascript directly influence how PHP or MySQL generates IDs. The code you've shared shows that perfectly, as it does not access any cookie. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at least susceptible to race conditions.

That is, suppose two clients try to generate a new random ID at the same time. Both of them read the current set of ID's from the database, and store this set into their own array in application space. They can exclude these from the next random ID they generate, but they don't know about the ID each other generates randomly. They could both generate the same ID as each other before they add their new record to the database.

This is a real thing that happens. It's also more and more likely as you fill up the database.

Suppose you have already stored values from 100000 to 999998 in the database. There's only one left to generate (999999). Both clients will both have to use the one remaining ID.

So no, it's not safe to design applications with race conditions.

You might think it will be rare that two clients will insert records at the same time. But there's an old saying:

[*One in a million is next Tuesday.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/one-in-a-million-is-next-tuesday)

In other words, the rare event you think will "never" happen will in fact happen much sooner than you think, because database transactions happen so frequently that even a rare chance succeeds once in a while, given enough tries.

To prevent the race condition with your random number scheme, you would have to lock the table, read all the ID's, generate your random number, then insert your row, and finally unlock the table. This is the only way to prevent another client from inserting its own row and using one of the unused ID's, which might be the same as the one your request is about to use.

The problem is that all those steps of locking and reading the table and unlocking take much more time than simply generating the next auto-increment ID. If concurrent clients need to insert, they tend to queue up, waiting for each other.

This is why most databases have an [auto-increment feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/example-auto-increment.html), that guarantees clients will not be given the same ID value, even if they insert new rows concurrently. The database can do this very fast, and support a high rate of concurrent inserts by many clients.

Besides the race condition, it also does create a server issue. If every INSERT is forced to do a table-scan of the whole table to collect the currently-used ID's, that adds latency to inserts, which gets worse and worse as the table grows larger.

Also the number of rows could eventually grow so holding an array of a million ID values in the application exceeds the [maximum memory an application request can allocate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit).

Comment: Thanks for this information! I've devised a system for creating an alternate user ID separate from the Primary_Key "user_id". I store it in a separate table than the "user" table. My program is in a separate php file than say the signup form, and is referenced after signup has been achieved and whilst redirecting into the landing page. This program auto-generates a unique ID and processes it into the alternate table. This would be something like username + random ID# + Website domain.  Guess it would be better to just search the DB rather than pull the data into an array? Thanks a "million"!

Comment: I have no idea what the purpose of your alternate user ID is. I would just use the auto-increment ID when I insert into a table. I don't know why you need an alternate user ID.

Comment: I wouldn't think it to be a good idea to use a user's ID publicly so I want one that can be displayed and not only that but be used as a communication means. If user (A) wants to send a message to user (B) they can contact them by their user unique ID. (username[A23%dC00142]@website.com. I accepted your answer because you're right, limiting may lead to a dead-end eventually. I am still curious if this method could lead to a security risk?

Comment: It depends on how users send messages, but I would think if one user can view the name of another user and send that user a message anyway, then there's no advantage to hiding the auto-increment ID. I've seen other people try to solve a hypothetical security flaw, but in my opinion, it's solved better by enforcing some limits on users messaging each other.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I truly appreciate it!