# Generate secure random password in PHP

Tags: php, string, random, passwords, generate

I've made a php function which generate random password.
But, sometimes, password length is different that I want (I fixed it to 10) and I don't understand why ?
I wish password don't start by special char if it possible.
Can you help me please ?

```
<?php
    function get_random_password() {
        $digits = range('0', '9');
        $lowercase = range('a', 'z');
        $uppercase = range('A', 'Z'); 
        $special = str_split('!@#$%^&*+=-_?.,:;<>(){}[]/|~`\'"');
        shuffle($digits);
        shuffle($special);
        shuffle($lowercase);
        shuffle($uppercase);
        $array_special = array_rand($special);
        $array_digits = array_rand($digits, 3);
        $array_lowercase = array_rand($lowercase, 3);
        $array_uppercase = array_rand($uppercase, 3);
        $password = str_shuffle(
            $special[$array_special].
            $digits[$array_digits[0]].
            $digits[$array_digits[1]].
            $digits[$array_digits[2]].
            $lowercase[$array_lowercase[0]].
            $lowercase[$array_lowercase[1]].
            $lowercase[$array_lowercase[2]].
            $uppercase[$array_uppercase[0]].
            $uppercase[$array_uppercase[1]].
            $uppercase[$array_uppercase[2]]
        );
        if (strlen($password) > 10) {
            $password = substr($password, 0, 10);
        }
        return $password;
    }
    for ($i=0;$i<=30;$i++) {
        echo get_random_password()."<br>";
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings)

Comment: Also, you should use `random_bytes` or `random_int`, rather than `array_rand`, to generate passwords or other "secure" random values.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570980/generating-a-random-code-in-php/64472183#64472183

Comment: If your password contains a `<` it may confuse the tags in the browser.  View the source in your browser to check.

Comment: Apart from the problem Nigel Ren saw, when I actually run your code all passwords are always 10 characters long. Always. My best guess is that you're not running the code you thing you are running.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code several times. It **always** returns passwords which are 10 chars long.

I see the following problems:

- you are printing it out in html, so chars like `<` and `>` can break your html code
- also line breaks could be a problem

To solve this:

- Do not print it out in browser, better test your function in a console.
- If you want to print it out in html, then you have to use the `htmlentities()` ([PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) function to display it correctly in the browser. Do **not** store the passwords with `htmlentities()` as this would replace the special characters in your passwords with the html entities.