# Generting random (alphanumeric) string in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings)

How to genearte random string in PHP? Numbers are not a problem, but how to deal with letters **efficiently**?

Answer (score 0):

You might be best of using the normal random function in combination with `chr`
From the php manual comments: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
    $random_string .= chr(rand(0,25)+65);
}
echo $random_string;
?>
```