# Create unique id with a length of 5 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know the `uniqid()` method to create lots of unique ids with a length of 7 or more, but what I want to create is a length of 5 unique id with no collision.

Is it possible to create 220.000 unique id's with a length of 5 and check if there is any collision?

Comment: sorry but letters and numbers should be able to create more than 220.00 unique ids or not?

Comment: Realized that after I've submitted. I always see ID's as `int` :)

Comment: Assuming you take the english alphabet (26 characters) and numeric characters 0-9 we have a total of 36 characters. The number of unique combinations is then given by 36^5 = 60466176 So this should be more than enough

Comment: great! and how to do that :-/

Comment: For an example method, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings

Comment: Maybe http://codepad.org/slExXQLQ ?

Comment: pankrates, that looks pretty good but i have the fear this could be very slow if its checking the whole array on every number if its collisioned. but very good answer, thanks for that!

Comment: @TedMosby that is not a good example because it uses `rand`

Comment: whats wrong with rand? hes checking if there is a collision within the array... should do what i want huh?

Comment: @Baba fyi, `str_shuffle()` implicitly uses `rand()` too :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you need or use a feature where you have to create unique string using PHP, and not using inbuilt functions like uniqid?

Comment: @Jack yes i know that i why `mt_rand` was used instead ... the  `str_shuffle` was to re arrange the string every time the function is called to reduce collision

Comment: @Baba I somehow doubt it does anything to reduce collision :)

Comment: @Jack did some simple test and i think and feeling lucky about add that there ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{
    echo randString(5),PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Output

```
7fh96
G93fd
97Q7E
90Wku
7Vby9
4678f
S11oe
67688
19D36
KC1bQ
```

Simple Collision Test

```
$hash = array();
$collision = 0;
while ( count($hash) < 220000 ) {
    $r = randString(5);
    if (isset($hash[$r])) {
        $collision ++;
        continue;
    }
    $hash[$r] = 1;
}

print(($collision / 220000)  * 100 . "% - ($collision)");
```

[Tested 100,000 times and always collision is always less that 0.02](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1FdqFU) which makes the function efficient for a 5 character set

```
0.011818181818182% - (26)
```

Function Used

```
function randString($length) {
    $char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $char = str_shuffle($char);
    for($i = 0, $rand = '', $l = strlen($char) - 1; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $rand .= $char{mt_rand(0, $l)};
    }
    return $rand;
}
```

Comment: these is not collision free, so you could store them as array keys and do this till your array have 220.000 keys

Comment: @JaMaBing a quick test shows that the function show about `0.1181` collision .. that can be easy resolved if the has are stored see http://codepad.viper-7.com/S0W8U1

Comment: I know, but he dont ask for random strings. So if he implemented your solution without collision detection, he get in trouble later.

Comment: `is it possible to create 220.000 unique id's with a length of 5 and check if there is any collision.` he already intends to check for collision

Comment: well i thought its better to check if there is any collision. of course i would prefer a way where no collision check is needed. anyways, i will try your code snippet and thanks for that, looks quite good for me! :)

Comment: @TedMosby Not having a collision detection is of course impossible; based on your alphabet size and number of codes you need, the probability is at least 0.024%. The [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) makes the odds even better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article

- [Create short IDs with PHP - Like Youtube or TinyURL](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl)

It explains how to generate short unique ids from your bdd ids, like youtube does.

Actually, the function in the article is very related to [php function base_convert](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.base-convert.php) which converts a number from a base to another (but is only up to base 36).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to use `uniqid()` function for making a string of particular length. Hence I experimented and came up with the following code:

```
<?php
    $number = uniqid();
    $varray = str_split($number);
    $len = sizeof($varray);
    $otp = array_slice($varray, $len-5, $len);
    $otp = implode(",", $otp);
    $otp = str_replace(',', '', $otp);
    print_r($otp);
?>
```

This works fine for me, as long as your site doesn't generate OTPs at a very fast rate, this should work fine!