# jQuery document ready function is overwritten by _layout.cshtml

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC porogram, I have index.cshtml including _layout.cshtml:

In _layout.cshtml, I have an information display:

```
<div id='pageTheme'> Operations Overview </div>
```

Which is in a header bar for displaying information related to the page. 
In document ready function, I have a button click function, which routes to a new page from MVC controller and in the function I have

```
$(“#pageTheme”).text(“Hello Kitty”);
```

When the button is clicked and the document ready function is executed, a new routed page shows up, I can see “Hello Kitty” showing up and then back to 
“Operations Overview”.
I thought the document ready function is executed after loading the new page, not going back to the page again. What did I do wrong?

The following is the details of the document ready function:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        // Click main / sub menu
        $("#nav  li  a").on("click", function () {
            $("#nav li").removeClass("menuActive");
            $(this).parents(".topMenu").addClass("menuActive");
            var mainMenuTitle = $(this).parents(".topMenu").children('a').text();
            $("#pageTheme").text(mainMenuTitle);
        });
    });
```

The following is the mainMenu, which is inside of _layout.cshtml

```
<ul id="nav">
            <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA" href='@Url.Action("Index", "SavedViews")'>Saved Views</a></li>
            <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA" > Administration</a> 
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "ServerLogs")>Server Logs</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "DirSet")>Directory Setting</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Site")>Locations</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "AccessPoint")>Wi-Fi Access Point</a></li> 

                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "ServerLogs")>TIS Server Logs</a></li> 

                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "SoftwareBaseLine")>Software Baselines</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "Car")> Cars</a></li> 
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("CarSeries", "Car")>Car Series</a></li> 
                    <!--We need a better way to handle the hiding and showing of functionality across projects-->
                    @if (Global.CompanyName == "Port Authority Transit Corporation")  // Video is for WMATA only
                    {
                    <li class="subMenu"> <a href=@Url.Action("Index", "ManagePassword")>Maintenance Password</a></li> 
                    }
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="topMenu"><a class="topMenuA" href=@Url.Action("Index", "JobManage")>Job Management</a></li>
</ul>
```

When submenu is clicked, it executes the routing: let's say:

```
href='@Url.Action("Index", "SavedViews")
```

Which is the index of Controller SavedViews. The following is the controller cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Fleet.Controllers
    {
        public class SavedViewsController : Controller
        {  
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

The following is index.chtml:

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Saved view for testing now</h2>

<LINK href="~/Content/css/SoftwareVersionPage.css" rel="stylesheet">  
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tableFilter")   
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jsonTable") 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Filtercss")
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/softwareVersion.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<div class="outerDivBody">  
    <div id="filterMenu">
        @Html.Partial("_FilterMenu")    
    </div>
    <div id="displayNoTitle">
        <p id="showNOofItems"> </p>
    </div>
    <div id="middleOuterDiv">
        <div id="filterDiv" class="halignDiv">
            <div class="filterTopRow"> </div>
            <div class="filterContent"></div>

            <p> Search </p>
            <div id="div_filterSearch">   
                <div>
                </div>     
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div id="MiddleRightSoftDiv" class="softwareVersionDiv">               
        </div>    
    </div>   
</div>
```

_layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - Quester Tangent FleetWise</title>

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

        @if (IsSectionDefined("AddFilesToHead"))
        {
            @RenderSection("AddFilesToHead", required: false)
        }
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <div id="headerstrip">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="headerstrip1">&nbsp;</div>
                <div  id="infoStrip">
                    <section id="pageTheme">
                        Operations Overview
                    </section>
                    <section id="ws_stat">   Disconnected   </section>                     
                </div>
                <div id ="companyLogo">
                    <A href="@Global.CompanyURL">
                        <IMG title="@Global.CompanyName" id="logo"  alt="@Global.CompanyName"  src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/")@Global.CompanyLogoFile"  > 
                    </A>
                </div>

                <div id="pageTitle"> </div>

                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                         @if (Session["MyMenu"] == null){
                            Session["MyMenu"] = Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_MainMenu.cshtml");
                          } 
                         @Session["MyMenu"]
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>
        </header>

        <div id="body"  class="content-wrapper">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>

    </body>
    @if (IsSectionDefined("AddPageScriptToFooter"))
    {
        @RenderSection("AddPageScriptToFooter", required: false)
    }
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There has to be more code then what you've given us. You saying a new page shows up but how, I don't see anything related to that.

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the current div on the page but then fetching a new page on the backend (which is why it looks like it is "reverting" back to "Operations Overview").  Is this button tied to a form?  As @ErikPhilips said... there has to be more code you can share with us.

Comment: Thanks Erik and Ballbin. I provided more code. Please take a look. I have had this problem for a while and I should spent time to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a value in your `href` it goes and fetches that page.  What you are seeing is the javascript code run before the browser gets a response back from the server.  So what happens is... the js change take affect then the new pages loads wiping out anything from the previous page.

You can stop this by padding in the event object and calling `preventDefault`...

```
$("#nav  li  a").on("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...//rest of your code...
});
```

I am guessing that you want to link to function normally since you are giving a value in the `href` attribute?  If that is case you can easily change the "pageTheme" text when the server renders the page.

In the view that calls your layout you can set the value into the `ViewBag`...

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"; //Or what ever view you are in...
    ViewBag.PageTheme = "Hello Kitty"; // Or what ever theme you want for the particular view
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Then in your layout you can change it to...

```
<section id="pageTheme">
    @ViewBag.PageTheme
</section>
```

Or the other option would be to add javascript so when the page loads the script would change it to the value you wanted for the page was just loaded.  But I would strongly urge you do it on the server side.

Hope this helps unless there is something I am completely missing?...

Comment: You are great, Ballbin. I got the same idea as you did. The only bitterness is that I have to add extra on each page, either in your way, or use javascript <script> pageTheme = "Hello Kitty" </script> at the bottom of each page, if we don't have a better way. In either way, it is equivalent to hard coding <section id="pageTheme"> Hello Kitty </Session>, which becomes naughty when I have many web pages in the site.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Have U got experience with setting client side session variable (javascript setting and fetching session variable)? If we can do that, then it is more beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: You can do local store or cookies.  Take a look at this SO question [client-side-js-session-library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952076/client-side-js-session-library) or this article [cookieless-javascript-session-variables/](http://www.sitepoint.com/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/)