# PHP Rand String Generator

Tags: php

How can I generate a random string, 20 characters long, A-Z (no lower case), 0-9 only?

I searched online but most scripts to do this are huge (50+ lines). Is there something simpler (maybe 1 line)?

Comment: Scrapping the answer I wrote as it was identical to the one linked here. Oh search boxes are heaven sent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings)

Answer (score 3):

Will this suffice ?

```
<?php
echo strtoupper(substr(sha1(uniqid()),0,20));
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
A71463EA326B72981D21
```

Comment: Pretty wiz :-) Nice one

Comment: Only generates 0-9A-F, leaving out 20 of the 36 possible chars.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a string with all the character you want that could be in the random string

```
$chars = 'ABCDEFG...0123456789';
```

and then create a for loop that picks a random letter or number in the chars string for 20 timer

```
$randstring = '';
$string_length;
for ($a = 0; $a < $string_length; $a++) {
  $randstring .= $chars[rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
}
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: Ticks all of the boxes, if I were the asker this is the answer I would accept.