# Give uploaded image a random name?

Tags: php

How do i give the image a random name instead of taking the name the image currently have when being uploaded?

```
if(file_exists('folder/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
      echo "Change ImageName<br> ";

    } 
    else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'folder/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
    $q = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET date=now(), image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE username= '$id'");

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings to help you make the name then replace $_FILES['file']['name'] with that plus '.jpg';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate a unique file name if you don't care about original names.

```
$newFileName = uniqid('uploaded-', true) 
    . '.' . strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'folder/' . $newFileName);
$q = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET date=now(), image = '".$newFileName."' WHERE username= '$id'");
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i get a dot before the image type?(eg jpg)

Comment: the call to pathinfo returns the file extension, so the file name will contain the proper extension, though I would add some contents check to ensure it really is an image. See the example snippet.

Answer (score 1):

See [StackOverflow Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings) to help you make the random name then replace `$_FILES['file']['name']` with the newly generated name plus `'.jpg';`

[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416/daniel)'s  answer seems quite smooth to me.