# How to create 7 digits alphanumeric in PHP for coupons?

Tags: php

How to create 7 or Nth digits alphanumeric coupon code in a fast way? I have checked to use `array_rand` or `rand` or `mt_rand` which function should I prefer. To make my code fast and get more random number.

Requirement:

1. It should be take random number from 0-9 and A-Z (not lowercase a-z).
2. Starting first to three characters should be from A-Z and remaining should be 0-9.
3. 0-9 and A-Z can be repeat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating (pseudo)random alpha-numeric strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings)

Comment: How fast exactly you need it? Generating random numbers -  pseudo or real isn't fast in anyway. How often you need to generate coupons and how many of them?

Comment: You could just get the first 7 characters returned by [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and uppercase them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Requirement:
>   1) It should be take random number from 0-9 and A-Z ( not
>   lowercase a-z).
>   2) Starting first to three characters should be from
>   A-Z and remaining should be 0-9.
>   3) 0-9 and A-Z can be repeat.

You can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [str_shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php), i.e.:

```
$partOne =  substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 3);    
$partTwo =  substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, 4);  
echo $partOne.$partTwo;
//ZPN1690
```

---

**Ideone Demo:**

http://ideone.com/OU3DuM

Comment: $alphabet=array('A','B','C');
$partOne=null;
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
   $partOne .= $alphabet[mt_rand(0, 2)];
}
same for $partTwo also I have to do. To generate 
3) 0-9 and A-Z can be repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Using `random_bytes` or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`.
Pass a length of 4 bytes as a parameter, remove the last character to get the 7 string coupon code.

```
for ($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++){

    $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4);
    $hex   = bin2hex($bytes);

    $coupon = substr($hex, 0, -1);
    print $coupon . PHP_EOL;

}
```

Will output

```
...
157d224
a46b8a8
83e208b
16a338a
ad7318a
55e405a
63e786a
ca016c5
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it easy, Use `str_suffle` and `substr` for random string.

```
$length = 7;    
$randomString =  substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);    
echo $randomString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function will create a random string

```
function generateRandomString($length = 7) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

echo genereteRandomString();
```

You can pass the desired length to the function too. The character for the string can be limited in the `$characters` variable

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateToken($length = 7)
{
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'; // add characters here
    $token = '';
    while(strlen($token) < $length) {
        $token .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
    }
    return $token;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will create n digit randon number. Try this:

```
$n = 7;
$chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$res = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars)-1)];
}
```