# Picking random color within the shades of gray color range

Tags: php, hex

How Can I pick a random color within a color hex range. I need to pick the gray shades only as seen in this link
[Link for gray](http://www.htmlportal.net/colors/shades-of-gray.php)

Here's my code

```
$color = sprintf('#%06X', mt_rand(444,EEE));
```

Here's the error
**Use of undefined constant EEE - assumed 'EEE'**

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `mt_rand()` on an alphanumeric range, which you have not defined, which I don't think will work like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124/generating-pseudorandom-alpha-numeric-strings

Comment: Useful? Since when? Did't you know that if you wrap it in quotes it will produce another error since it was actually picking random?
`mt_rand() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see on your link, Grays (or greys) have the same Red Green and Blue values, so you need to generate one 2 digit number and use that in in 3 positions.

Just picking a random number between 222 and EEE could end up with say 3F7 which is in the range but not a gray.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
$n = mt_rand(0, 255);
background-color: rgb(<?= $n; ?>, <?= $n; ?>, <?= $n; ?>)
```